# how to stop Windows Server 2016 from standby mode?

Tags: windows, hibernate, power-management, windows-server, standby

My Windows Server 2016 enters in standby mode without following any regular pattern and I need it "awake" 24/7 because I connect to it through remote connection. Therefore, when this happens, I can't use the remote connection and when I physically see the server, the power button is orange and blinking.

I've tried:

```
powercfg.exe /hibernate off
```

but still, at random times, this happens.

The output of powercfg /list is:

```
Combinaciones de energía existentes (* activas)
------------------------------------------------
GUID de plan de energía: 381b4222-f694-41f0-9685-ff5bb260df2e  (Equilibrado) *
GUID de plan de energía: 8c5e7fda-e8bf-4a96-9a85-a6e23a8c635c  (Alto rendimiento)
GUID de plan de energía: a1841308-3541-4fab-bc81-f71556f20b4a  (Economizador)
```

which means: balanced, high perfomance and economizer and the active option is the balanced one.
Any idea on how to solve this?

Comment: hibernate is different from a power plan.... you should go to the settings panel and look through everything relating to power settings.

Comment: do powercfg /list and put your output on the question

Comment: @spikey_richie just did it. thank you!

Comment: Ok so now check the properties of the power configuration "Equilibrado"

Comment: have you been able to find out the reason/fix?

Answer (score 0):

Go to *Control panel > Power options > Change plan settings*,
and set "Put the computer to sleep" to "Never".

If this still occurs, run `powercfg -energy`, as described in the article
[How to Create a Power Efficiency Diagnostics Report in Windows 10](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/5148-create-power-efficiency-diagnostics-report-windows-10-a.html).
Post the result file somewhere so we can have a look at it.

Comment: thanks for your answer. I already edited my plan settings and, in the option "sleep" it says "allow reactivation temporizers" and it's set as disabled. Also, I run the command **powercfg -energy** and unfortunately, the report is in Spanish but I saw one of the errors that says "the system firmware (BIOS) doesn't allow S4 (sleep)". Another one is: " waiting time for sleep mode disables (with AC)"...I think Windows Server 2016 has slightly different power options than Windows 10 and I can't find a clair way to set it up.